# How to change the Rundeck web interface port from 4440 to 80

Tags: rundeck

I'm trying to use [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) on Ubuntu 14.04.

**How do I change the web interface port from 4440 (default) to 80?**

The port number seems to be referred to in various config locations (including `/etc/rundeck/profile` and `/etc/rundeck/framework.properties`) but changing these had no effect for me and I can't find a specific section in the documentation on changing the web port.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proxy pass with either Apache or Nginx. Its a solution..

You needed to modify these files from 4440 to 80

framework.properties
profile
rundeck-config.properties

But you will get the following java exception when trying to run in 80.

java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Hence apache or nginx proxy pass is the working solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you can use two rules iptables

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4440
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4440 -j ACCEPT